# What is the mass of rotation of Earth?

Tags: mass, relativity, earth, rotation, mass-energy

This question means "what is the additional mass which Earth has due to its rotational kinetic energy and mass-energy equivalence, as opposed to hypothetical non-rotating Earth"?

How could I calculate it?

Comment: homework question?? well rotational energy E=1/2I(omega)^2=mc^2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence of prior effort.